# Context Menu in QGraphicsWidget using addAction()

Tags: qt, qt5.4

I have a custom QGraphicsWidget in Qt5.4 to which I'm trying to add a context menu.  In the item's init() routine I add two QAction items like this:

```
bool MyGraphicsWidget::init()
{
    this->addAction(new QAction("Rotate &Left", this));
    this->addAction(new QAction("Rotate &Right", this));
}
```

But when I try to pull up the context menu (right-clicking in Windows) nothing shows up.

The documentation seems to say I can just add the QAction items and the context menu will just work without my having to override mouse events or context menu events.  I've tried changing the contextMenuPolicy in the QGraphicsView to **ActionsContextMenu** and the window flags on the QGraphicsWidget to **ItemIsSelectable** but to no avail.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `contextMenuEvent` with `QMenu`:

```
void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu menu;
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Rotate &Left", this));
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Rotate &Right", this));
    menu.exec(event->screenPos());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I ended up doing, but it seems odd that QGraphicsWidget would have methods for adding actions if there was no way to display a context menu with those actions. Are you sure **QGraphicsWidget::addAction()** doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps a bug in Qt. But since `QGraphicsWidget` inherits `QGraphicsItem`, documentation says you need to manually create `QMenu` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#contextMenuEvent

Comment: Yeah, I think it's either an API bug or there's another flag/property I need to set to enable the context menu. It looks like the QAction-related methods were addded to QGraphicsWidget so that we wouldn't have to override contextMenuEvent(). At any rate, thanks for your assistance.